Looking for film/mini-series about a prisoner who astral projects - UK TV
sorry I've not got many details about this, I was quite young at the time and only remember it vaguely.
So, this was a British TV movie or mini-series somewhere between 1990-1995 on UK TV. It involved a guy who is sent to prison for something and, while there, he starts learning about meditation and separating his mind from his body.
He eventually gets to the point where he's able to 'astral project', that is travel outside his body and outside of the prison in his mind. I can't remember much of what he does during this, I do remember he finds his wife/girlfriend on the outside having an affair.
However, the longer or further he goes from his body leaves it weaker and weaker, and the whole thing ends with him waking up in a coffin. Apparently he wandered too far for too long and they thought he had died in his cell. I remember the last shot is the camera pulling back from his grave with him shouting beneath but with nobody there to hear him - now I think about it, he must have had a stingy embalmer and no autopsy.
Sound familiar to anyone?

+1 for a good question and joke. ;) The Astral Factor has a similar plot, but it's US and from 1978. (And someone gets buried alive, but it's a mess.)

I believe that this is I'll be watching You, the first episode of the series Ghosts
The plot is pretty much as you described. The main character learns how to leave his body after a near death experience. He discovers that his wife is having an affair and plans revenge. If I recall correctly, his body is discovered in his cell while he is "haunting" his wife and it is the attempt to revive him that causes the trouble.
See also here
